# Loading additional files (ps1) for use in PowerShell modules

Tags: powershell

I've `PowerShell Module` (lets call it `PSModule`) in which I've defined as follows in .psd1

```
# Script files (.ps1) that are run in the caller's environment prior to importing this module.
ScriptsToProcess = @('Enums\MessageType.ps1')
```

This is added there so that the file `MessageType.ps1` that holds the just `Enums` can be reused across multiple files.

This file looks like:

```
enum MessageType {
   None
   Something
}
```

An example of this is `PSWriteWord` - https://github.com/EvotecIT/PSWriteWord module. This is supposed to keep Enums in it's own folder and still load them when module is started.

This works fine most of the time. I've run scripts without issues. Now I've a weird situation where I've created: script1.ps1 - that I call.

Content of script1.ps1

```
Import-Module PSModule -Force

Import-Module PSOtherModule -Force

Call-Me -Parameters <params> # part of PSOtherModule
```

Now within Call-Me function from PSOtherModule I call

```
Do-Something
do-Something

Call-OtherFunction # function from PSModule
```

It will work when running in ISE or VSCode...

Now if I rerun the same script from `Task Scheduler` it won't load the `MessageType` which essentially will fail at some point. It seems that it simply skips the processing of `ScriptsToProcess`.

Now if you do:

```
Do-Something
do-Something
Import-Module PSModule
Call-OtherFunction # function from PSModule
```

It still won't work ... But this will...

```
Do-Something
do-Something
Import-Module PSModule -Force
Call-OtherFunction # function from PSModule
```

So now I'm struggling to find a way to properly add ENUMS as separate files to my modules and keep this running without weird workaround with IMport-Module just before calling PSModule.

I've found this: https://d-fens.ch/2014/11/26/bug-powershell-scripts-in-scriptstoprocess-attribute-appear-as-loaded-modules/ which does what it says it does well but it doesn't solve my problem.

Anyone knows a way to workaround it? I tried putting fullpath to ScriptsToProcess thinking that Enums path in ScriptsToProcess may be somehow overwritten ... but no..

My .psm1 file looks like this:

```
#Get public and private function definition files.
$Public = @( Get-ChildItem -Path $PSScriptRoot\Public\*.ps1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue )
$Private = @( Get-ChildItem -Path $PSScriptRoot\Private\*.ps1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue )
$Enums = @( Get-ChildItem -Path $PSScriptRoot\Enums\*.ps1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue )

#Dot source the files
Foreach ($import in @($Public + $Private + $Enums)) {
    Try {
        . $import.fullname
    } Catch {
        Write-Error -Message "Failed to import function $($import.fullname): $_"

    }
}
Export-ModuleMember -Function '*'
[string] $ManifestFile = '{0}.psd1' -f (Get-Item $PSCommandPath).BaseName;
$ManifestPathAndFile = Join-Path -Path $PSScriptRoot -ChildPath $ManifestFile;
if ( Test-Path -Path $ManifestPathAndFile) {
    $Manifest = (Get-Content -raw $ManifestPathAndFile) | iex;
    foreach ( $ScriptToProcess in $Manifest.ScriptsToProcess) {
        $ModuleToRemove = (Get-Item (Join-Path -Path $PSScriptRoot -ChildPath $ScriptToProcess)).BaseName;
        if (Get-Module $ModuleToRemove) {
            Remove-Module $ModuleToRemove;
        }
    }
}
```

I added Enums just now but it doesn't change anything... The thing after Export-Module is for removing the Script from Modules (as in the link). It doesn't matter for my problem.

Can be  seen here:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To work around this issue I've opted to use `Add-Type` with C# code that is compiled on demand instead of PowerShell's own `enum` construct. It works.

```
<#
enum MessageType {
    Alert
    Cancel
    Disable
    Download
    Minus
    Check
    Add
    None
}

#>


Add-Type -TypeDefinition @"
   public enum MessageType
   {
    Alert,
    Cancel,
    Disable,
    Download,
    Minus,
    Check,
    Add,
    None
   }
"@
```

Answer (score 4):

Note:

- If you're just looking for an **effective solution** based on on-demand compilation of C# code via `Add-Type`, see 
  [MadBoy's own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51324293/45375).
- If you'd like to **understand the issue**, including *why* an `Add-Type`-based solution helps, read on.

---

The **behavior is as expected**:

Your `Import-Module PSModule -Force` call in `script.ps1` dot-sources `Enums\MessageType.ps1` *only* in `script.ps1`'s scope.

Therefore, when `Call-Me` from module `PSOtherModule` runs, *it* knows nothing about the enums you've loaded into `script.ps1`, because `PSOtherModule` has its own scope (that doesn't inherit from the caller).

The reason that `Import-Module PSModule -Force` in `Call-Me` works is that you're forcing *reloading* of the module *in the context of `PSOtherModule`*, which therefore then dot-sources `Enums\MessageType.ps1`, making the `enum` available (whereas omitting `-Force` would be a no-op, since PowerShell has already loaded the module (which happens session-globally) and therefore doesn't process the module manifest and its `ScriptsToProcess` entry again).

Yes, **using `Add-Type` with a string containing C# code that is compiled on demand solves the problem** (as shown in [the answer you've since posted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51324293/45375)), but for an unrelated reason: **`Add-Type`-added types are invariably *session-global***, irrespective of in what scope `Add-Type` is called.

To **achieve the same effect with *PowerShell* `enum` (or `class`) definitions** - and thereby solve your problem - you need to:

- include the `enum` definitions directly in your `PSModule.psm1` file.
- use the `using module PSModule` directive instead of an `Import-Module PSModule` cmdlet call in order to import your module - only `using module` makes PowerShell-based `enum` and `class` definitions available outside the module, and then also *session-globally*.

---

**Optional background information:**

- `enum` and `class` definitions are a recent addition to PowerShell (v5), and they're not part of the module-export mechanism.

  - Outside of modules, `enum` and `class` definitions are local to the scope they're defined in / dot-sourced into.
  - If you make `enum` and `class` definitions part of a module (`*.psm1`) *and* you import that module with `using module`, these definitions do become available, but invariably *all* of them, and invariably *session-globally* (as do `Add-Type`-based types, although they do so even with `Import-Module`).
  - If you use `Import-Module` instead of `using module`, the `class` and `enum` definitions that are part of the module are effectively *private*.
- Many fixes and enhancements to `enum` and `class` definitions are pending as of Windows PowerShell v5.1 / PowerShell Core v6.1.0:

  - [This meta GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/6652) tracks all of them.
  - Making `Import-Module` see a module's `enum` and `class` definitions too is discussed [in this issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/2449#issuecomment-255506786); while fundamentally, possible, the fact that `Import-Module` executes at *runtime* whereas `using module` executes at *parse time* precludes certain use cases with `Import-Module` (in short: `class` definitions referencing other `class` definitions).
  - Separately, being able to explicitly control *which* `enum` and `class` definitions are to be exported - analogous to how you can selectively export functions, aliases, and variables - is being discussed [in this issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/6293).